# Why Linux doesn't need drivers

Tags: linux, driver, hardware

I was said that hardware access is done by memory mapping. It would be natural for different vendors to use different memory addresses even for one hardware type(chipset, wifi adapter and so on). So, if that's true, then driver goes along for each device as Windows does. But if addresses are different how does Linux developers knew that specifics? If they remain same is
there any free specification for each hardware type? Thanks.

Comment: Linux does use drivers. They just happen to be shipped with the kernel, most of the time..

Comment: look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39182/why-dont-you-need-to-update-drivers-or-do-you
I found this very useful...

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are incorrect.  Linux does use drivers, and the developers need to know the specifics to make the driver.

Some device types are common enough that a single driver can be used against that hardware type (de-facto standard, such as the SB16 and its clones, or the NE2000 clones).

Other devices have generic drivers because they were designed according to a specification which is amenable to a common driver (examples include AHCI; USB OHCI, UHCI, EHCI, and XHCI; USB mass storage devices; USB audio device class; and USB HID class).